# Next js Image error for url request solve?

Tags: next.js, self-signed-certificate

I use next js Image tag to render my images and optimize them but when I share the url of my image as src to the Image tag. it says self signed certificate error and doesn't return the image
what should I do?

```
<Image
 className={`${isSmall ? styles.SmallImg : styles.Img}`}
 src={img}
 alt={title}
 width={400}
 height={300}
 quality={80}
/>
```

this returns the error instead of image

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering a `self-signed certificate` error, running your app with the [`--experimental-https` flag](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-cli#https-for-local-development) may help. This feature is available starting from version 13.5.1 and later.

Comment: I tried your way bu still when I want to load an image from foreign url with <image>, it gives me self-signed certificate and in my console gives me 500 request code.

Comment: @AlirezaShirzadi I can't tell what's the problem, it might be the [`remotepatterns`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#remotepatterns)

Comment: I fixed my remote patterns. I'm sure that's not my problem.